# rake error when load production db schema

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake

Here is the error running rake for loading production db schema (mysql 5.1.45):

```
$ rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production --trace
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
No such middleware to insert before: ActionDispatch::Static
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:119:in `assert_index'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:83:in `insert'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/configuration.rb:38:in `block in merge_into'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/configuration.rb:37:in `each'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/configuration.rb:37:in `merge_into'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:445:in `app'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:37:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
D:/rails_proj/emclab-failed/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:78:in `require'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:78:in `require_environment!'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
c:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `load'
c:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
```

Please disregard the following: stackoverflow requires more words than the error message to explain the situation. Error message is better than any words!

Any suggestion to fix the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify another piece of middleware to insert into the front of the middleware stack.  Instead, you can specify just an index number.  For example:

```
config.middleware.insert_before(0, ::API::Throttle)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [someone who had a similar problem](http://www.stephenwalker.com/2010/08/issue-using-insert_afterbefore-actiondispatchstatic/), you may need to go into `config/application.rb` and replace:

```
config.middleware.insert_after('ActionDispatch::Static', '::API::Throttle')
```

with this line instead:

```
config.middleware.insert_before('Rack::Lock', '::API::Throttle')
```

Hope this helps!